# Redirect softwareupdate stdout in file and tail -n1

Tags: bash

I write a script which interacts with swiftdialog and `softwareupdate`.

The problem is that I can't redirect the download progress in log file before `softwareupdate` finished his execution.

Here is the part of the code that takes care of that

```bash
    updateDialog "progresstext: Download $targetVersion "

    softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer –full-installer-version $upgradeVersion >"$softwareupdateExecutionLog" &
    sleep 0.5

    while [[ -n $(pgrep -u "$loggedInUser" "softwareupdate") ]]; do
        softwareupdateProgressText=$(head -n1 "$softwareupdateExecutionLog")
        updateDialog "progresstext: ${softwareupdateProgressText}"
        updateScriptLog "${softwareupdateProgressText}"
        sleep 0.5
    done
    updateDialog "progress: 100"
```

In my tests, I noticed, the stdout are redirected to a log file, but when I do `softwareupdate -l >$softwareupdateExecutionLog & sleep 1; tail -n1 $softwareupdateExecutionLog` I get nothing back.
If `softwareupdate` is interrupted no log is recorded in the file. And `cat $softwareupdateExecutionLog` is empty.

But, if I wait until the end of the command execution it’s ok. `softwareupdate -l >$softwareupdateExecutionLog; sleep 1; tail -n1 $softwareupdateExecutionLog`

Is it me who makes a mistake in the redirections or is it a bipolarity of Apple?

Comment: You might want to look at the tee command to allow write to log and to stdout and tail at the same time

Comment: I don't want to write to stdout

Comment: Isn't that what tail is doing?

Comment: I misspoke. I was talking about the tee command. I don't want to duplicate stdout